# how to show ajax respone partially in hidden value and partially in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show success result from ajax in hidden value and in div. but its showing in one or other

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" ID="piechartval" value="HERE" />
   <div class="rankadvancement "><img src="Assets/Images/imgLoading.gif" style="width: 16px;" />HERE<div>

here is my javacript:

 success: function(data) {
 //var $response = $(data);
                        //oGlobal = $response.find('#pie').text()
                        //alert(oGlobal);
                        var selector ="";
                        var control = '<%=piechartval.ClientID%>';
                        var str = data;
                        var n =str.lastIndexOf('</span>');
                        n = n.replace("</span>","");
                        var a = str.substring(n + 1,str.length - 6);
                        alert(a);
                        document.getElementById(control).value = a; ----- this value in hidden
                        $(selector).html('').html(a);  
                        $('.rankadvancement').html(data); --- this one in div
                    }
```

Thanks!!

I modified my result and now i want to see whole result in hidden value.
But its only displaying this part in output though hidden variable has full value  (

```
<div class='col-sm-4'>
                       <div class='pie-chart1 pie-chart pie-number easyPieChart' data-percent=33% style='width: 220px; height: 220px; line-height: 220px;'>33% <canvas width='220' height ='220'/></div>
```

)

But when i copy result and hardcode in aspx page it works fine but not through ajax.

Here is wat i get on success:

```
 <div class='col-sm-4'>
                   <div class='pie-chart1 pie-chart pie-number easyPieChart' data-percent=33% style='width: 220px; height: 220px; line-height: 220px;'>33% <canvas width='220' height ='220'/></div>

               </div>
                <div  class='rankadvancement'>
                    <div class='row-fluid'>
                        <span class='span2'>
                            <div class='percent'>33%</div>

                        </span>
                        <span class='span10'>
                            <a href='javascript:loadRankAdvancement(6);' class='next'><img src='Assets/Images/btnArrowRight.png' /></a>
                            <a href='javascript:loadRankAdvancement(4);' class='previous'><img src='Assets/Images/btnArrowLeft.png' /></a>
                            <h3>Pearl Ambassador</h3>
                            <div class='progress progress-magenta'>
                                <div class='bar' style='width: 33%'></div>

                            </div>

                        </span>

                    </div>
                    <div class='goals'>
                        <div class='clearfix'></div>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

tried but not working : I can see the value in hidden varibale but actually can't see the result on web page :

```
<!///<input name="ctl00$Content$piechartval" type="hien" id="Content_piechartval" class="piechartval" value=" <div class='col-sm-4'><div class='pie-chart1 pie-chart pie-number easyPieChart' data-percent=33% style='width: 220px; height: 220px; line-height: 220px;'>33% <canvas width='220' height ='220'/></div></div><div  class='rankadvancement' <img src='Assets/Images/imgLoading.gif' style='width: 16px;'><div class='row-fluid'><span class='span2'><div class='percent'>33%</div></span><span class='span10'><a href='javascript:loadRankAdvancement(6);' class='next'><img src='Assets/Images/btnArrowRight.png' /></a><a href='javascript:loadRankAdvancement(4);' class='previous'><img src='Assets/Images/btnArrowLeft.png' /></a><h3>Pearl Ambassador</h3><div class='progress progress-magenta'><div class='bar' style='width: 33%'></div></div></span></div><div class='goals'><div class='clearfix'></div></div></div>"
```

Comment: please re-read your question and judge if we can tell what you are asking. Please be more clear.

Comment: In what way is this not working?  When you step through this in a debugger, are you parsing out the values you expect?  What are you actually setting in the elements?

Comment: What is "var selector" for and why isn't it set? Why not set hidden text value with $("#piechartval") instead of getElementById?

Comment: I am getting html result and partially i want to show in hidden value and full data in div (div class="rankadvancement ">) nad value of a in my hidden variable piechartval

Comment: @user207888: Yes, you explained that much in the question.  But we can't debug this for you.  For example, when you set an element's value to the variable `a`, what is actually *in* the variable `a`?  What is in `data`?  Step through this code in a debugger and be more specific about where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not use markup in your server response but stick to JSON. My wild guess is you are snagging the `input` or `div` tag with bad markup. If you return JSON then it is as simple as.

```
success: function (data) {
  $('#piechartval').val(data.val);
  $('.rankadvancement').text(data.val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my own understanding all you need is to update the input value attribute

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" ID="piechartval" value="HERE" />

success: function(data) {

     $('input#piechartval').attr(value,data); --- this one in hidden input
     $('.rankadvancement').html(data); --- this one in div
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code and see what happens:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" class="piechartval" ID="piechartval" value="HERE" />
   <div class="rankadvancement "><img src="Assets/Images/imgLoading.gif" style="width: 16px;" />HERE<div>



 success: function(data) {

     $('.piechartval').val(data); --- this one in hidden input
     $('.rankadvancement').html(data); --- this one in div
}
```

Edit: on a side note, use a class on the hidden div, as the ID will change because of the `runat="server"`. fixed the code to reflect that.